# git не видит файлы

Tags: yii2, git, phpstorm, composer, link

Работаю с Yii2 (PhpStorm). После успешной закачки пакета с помощью композера (composer require package_name --ignore-platform-reqs) git не видит эти файлы, а вместо них показывает один файл со знаком вопроса. В vendor'e все файлы есть, но не подсвечиваются как новые/измененные. Слышал, что это git может делать что-то вроде ссылок, но мне нужно четко видеть, что я коммичу. Может кто сталкивался. Заранее всем спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Ну так папка vendor во всех фреймфорках всегда в гитигноре, после установки какого либо пакета у вас появляются в изменениях **composer.json** и **composer.lock** чтобы когда вы будете накатывать проект на прод можно было просто запустить **composer install** для установки именно тех версий проекта которые у вас установлены на dev сервере

Answer (score 0):

Вы сохраняете только проект.
Файлы которые загружает composer находятся в папке vendor и никогда не находятся в видении GIT'a. тк эти файлы подгружаются автоматически из своих репозиториев.

Тут проблем никаких нет, это нормальное поведение PhpStorm и GIT'aв том числе.